# How to pass default parser in REST Assured?

Tags: json, api, parsing, automation, rest-assured

I am trying to Automate API using REST Assured. Below is the Error I got in during executing the API Test Case :-

> testNotifications(com.api.truValue.test.notifications.NotificationsTest)  Time elapsed: 1.832 sec  <<< FAILURE!
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>
> Cannot invoke the path method because no content-type was present in the response and no default parser has been set.
>
> You can specify a default parser using e.g.:
>   RestAssured.defaultParser = Parser.JSON;
>
> at com.api.truValue.test.notifications.NotificationsTest.testNotifications(NotificationsTest.java:35)

Please let me know how to resolve this or How to Pass Default Parser.

Comment: You need to post your code...

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is in the error you received: `You can specify a default parser using e.g.: RestAssured.defaultParser = Parser.JSON;`

When setting up RestAssured, add the following line: `RestAssured.defaultParser = Parser.JSON;`

Alternatively, and probably better, the service you are testing should populate the `content-type` header in its responses.