# Response body of a Post Request can't be displayed

Tags: java, json, content-type, rest-assured

I wonder if anyone can help. I am trying to send a post request to create an item and I get the correct  the status code back, but not the response body. I am fairly new to APIs',so, bit confused by this. Googling hasn't helped either. Here's my code:-

```
public void createGoods() {
    RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();
    RestAssured.baseURI = "http://192.168.0.31:8081/transit-api/clothes?_dc=159053130885&productId=1";
    JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
    requestParams.put("productId", "1");
    requestParams.put("productDeploymentId", "1");
    requestParams.put("displayableId", goodsDisplayable);
    requestParams.put("createdUserName", "null");
    requestParams.put("product", "null");
    requestParams.put("productDescription", "");
    requestParams.put("createdDate", "null");
    requestParams.put("lastEventDate", "null");
    requestParams.put("progressDescription", "");
    requestParams.put("progressDate", "null");
    requestParams.put("active", true);
    requestParams.put("treatmentMilestones", "null");
    requestParams.put("status", "null");
    requestParams.put("stopComment", "");
    requestParams.put("primaryIdentifierString", "");
    requestParams.put("isPrimaryIdentifierAvailable", false);
    httpRequest
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9")
            .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
            .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
            .sessionId(sessionId);

    httpRequest.body(requestParams.toJSONString());
    Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.POST);

    System.out.println("RESPONSE body is--->>>>" + response.getBody().asString());
    System.out.println("Status code is----------------->>>" + response.getStatusCode());

}
```

}

The response I get is below:-

```
>>>>

RESPONSE body is---createTreatment----------->>>>*io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@55259aa7*

Status code is ----------------->>>200

Step failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke the path method because no content-type was present in the response and no default parser has been set.
You can specify a default parser using e.g.:
RestAssured.defaultParser = Parser.JSON;

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
    at io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl$_path_closure5.doCall(RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.groovy:392)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass default parser in REST Assured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234485/how-to-pass-default-parser-in-rest-assured)

Answer (score 1):

parsing is a way to read data from your response. Set the below as your default parser.

```
RestAssured.defaultParser = Parser.JSON;

result read!
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have noticed it doesn't have Content-Type in it's response headers when I post it from my method in Java. However, the same request does have Content-Type in its response when I post from Postman and it works fine. I tried adding the the parsor too but it does still work. From the mothod:-HEADERS----->Server=Apache-Coyote/1.1 X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff Content-Length=0 Date=Sun, 14 Jun 2020 13:39:34 GMT.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a default parser for REST Assured:

```
RestAssured.defaultParser = Parser.JSON;
```

See an example here: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/rest-assured-4.3.0/examples/rest-assured-itest-java/src/test/java/io/restassured/itest/java/DefaultParserITest.java#L44-L52

Alternatively, make sure that the service you're testing returns a valid `Content-Type` HTTP response header.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have noticed it doesn't have Content-Type in it's response headers when I post it from my method in Java. However, the same request does have Content-Type in its response when I post from Postman and it works fine. I tried adding the the parsor too but it does still work. From the mothod:-HEADERS----->Server=Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff
Content-Length=0
Date=Sun, 14 Jun 2020 13:39:34 GMT.

Comment: This hints to an empty response body which doesn't need a `Content-Type`, see the `Content-Length` HTTP response header.